# python launch.json file not passing

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-3.9

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjXYC.png)

I upgraded from python 3.10 to pyton 3.9 and got this error what is the solution

Comment: Moving from Python 3.10 to 3.9 is a _downgrade_, not an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade the version of the Python extension to solve it such as `v2021.10.1317843341`.

Or you can edit

`"when": "!virtualWorkspace && shellExecutionSupported"`

to

`"when": "!virtualWorkspace"`

in `vscode-python/package.json` at the line of `1496`.

Some people have run across the same problem, you can refer to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17952) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136712) for more information.

Comment: @beytullahbyram Have you solved the problem? if this is helpful, could you accept this answer? thanks, and have a good day : )